# Connect to the SOAP API without using the SDK wrappers

Tags: marketing-cloud, soap-api

I am fairly new to APIs but I get the how a REST API works quite well. THE Exact Target REST API V1 doesn't have the features that I am currently after so I am wanting to see if I can make use of the SOAP API instead. Unfortunately I am not using one of the languages that has an API wrapper written for it. I am using R. 
Is anyone able to point me in the right direction for some clear documentation on how to do a call to the soap api from a non standard language?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the raw SOAP WSDL's from [Getting Started Developers and the ExactTarget API - WSDL Links](https://help.exacttarget.com/en/technical_library/web_service_guide/getting_started_developers_and_the_exacttarget_api/).

From there you can drill into the Basic API Tasks, such as [Creating a Subscriber](https://help.exacttarget.com/en/technical_library/web_service_guide/technical_articles/creating_a_subscriber/#section_10). This includes the Sample SOAP Envelope.

Between the WSDL and the SOAP Envelope it would just be a matter of the implementation in the language of your choice.