# ContinueRequest within the soap envelope

Tags: marketing-cloud, soap-api

From my previous question ([Connect to the SOAP API without using the SDK wrappers](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/87972/connect-to-the-soap-api-without-using-the-sdk-wrappers)) I have managed to implement a successful call to the exact target soap API and receive some correct responses.

I now encounter the limit of 2500 records and am wondering how or where to (or even if I can) insert the ContinueRequest call in the soap envelope so I can continue to request the rest of the records.

Documentation of the ContinueRequest is [here](https://help.exacttarget.com/en/technical_library/web_service_guide/technical_articles/continuerequest_2500records/)

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

UPDATE: 2015-08-17
After further searching through the very haphazard documentation for ExactTarget I found that if you add an item `<ContinueRequest>RequestID</ContinueRequest>` to your SOAP envelope it all seems to work perfectly.

Example SOAP Envelope to retrieve all subscribers:

```
<Envelope xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <Header>
    <fueloauth xmlns="http://exacttarget.com"> auth_token </fueloauth>
  </Header>
  <Body>
    <RetrieveRequestMsg xmlns="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI">
      <RetrieveRequest>
        <ObjectType>Subscriber</ObjectType>
        <Properties>CreatedDate</Properties>
        <Properties>Client.ID</Properties>
        <Properties>EmailAddress</Properties>
        <Properties>SubscriberKey</Properties>
        <Properties>Status</Properties>
        <Properties>UnsubscribedDate</Properties>
        <Properties>ID</Properties>
        <Properties>Client.PartnerClientKey</Properties>
      </RetrieveRequest>
    </RetrieveRequestMsg>
  </Body>
</Envelope>
```

Once you've got your first batch of 2500 records back you need to send the following as the next packet:

```
<Envelope xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <Header>
    <fueloauth xmlns="http://exacttarget.com"> auth_token </fueloauth>
  </Header>
  <Body>
    <RetrieveRequestMsg xmlns="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI">
      <RetrieveRequest>
        <ContinueRequest>requestID</ContinueRequest>
        <ObjectType>Subscriber</ObjectType>
        <Properties>CreatedDate</Properties>
        <Properties>Client.ID</Properties>
        <Properties>EmailAddress</Properties>
        <Properties>SubscriberKey</Properties>
        <Properties>Status</Properties>
        <Properties>UnsubscribedDate</Properties>
        <Properties>ID</Properties>
        <Properties>Client.PartnerClientKey</Properties>
      </RetrieveRequest>
    </RetrieveRequestMsg>
  </Body>
</Envelope>
```

Where the `requestID` is the request ID that was returned from your last SOAP request. The OverallStatus message lets you know if there are more records with a message of `MoreDataAvailable`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add `<ContinueRequest>requestID</ContinueRequest>` within the `RetreiveRequest` section of the SOAP Envelope.

Answer (score 0):

I believe paging is only available in REST, which is why the SDK (or at least the javaSDK) uses REST for a data fetch.  Hope this helps!

Comment: The soap documentation talks to only returning 2500 records. It has also been my experience with preliminary calls that the soap api only returns 2500 records at a time. Undortunately the rest api isn't very comprehensive.

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify you repeat call much further. In the repeat

```xml
<Envelope xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <Header>
        <fueloauth xmlns="http://exacttarget.com"> auth_token </fueloauth>
    </Header>
    <Body>
        <RetrieveRequestMsg xmlns="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI">
            <RetrieveRequest>
            <ContinueRequest>requestID</ContinueRequest>            
            </RetrieveRequest>
        </RetrieveRequestMsg>
    </Body>
</Envelope>
```

Request id is already linked to select and filter part internally, you can simply it further